# "Opening file failed" error when using Unity 2019 w/ JetBrains Rider IDE

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

I am using Unity 2019.2.10f1 and Rider 2019.2. However, when editing the code in Rider and then switching back over to Unity, I **almost** always receive this error message:

`Opening file XXX: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

[image: screenshot]

Since the files being referenced is a temporary file, I am assuming this might have something to do with Rider saving a temporary file that Unity notices and then tries to load it (but it has since been deleted).

There is the "safe write" option in Rider that could be helpful, but I am hesitant to turn that off:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to avoid this? Clicking the `Cancel` button has been working fine, but it is, obviously, a bit annoying.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/1241) thread. It seems to fix this issue by either unselecting `safe write` or updating unity to the latest version.

Comment: Check your antivirus settings, it maybe your antivirus has the file locked